# Need some assistance with my Unit Test using Moq regarding await emailClient.SendAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, nunit

I am really battling with creating an Unit Moq test for my email function and was wondering if anyone could help me. I think I have most of it right but still something is broken. Thanks in advance

Below is the actual implementation code:

```
public async Task Email(string htmlContent, string? connectionString, string? subject, string? sender, string? recipient)
        {
            try
            {
                // Encode HTML content to Base-64
                string base64Content = EncodeToBase64(htmlContent);


                Console.WriteLine("Sending email...");


                // Assuming emailClient is an instance of some EmailClient class
                var emailClient = new EmailClient(connectionString); // replace EmailClient with the actual type
                var emailSendOperation = await emailClient.SendAsync(
                    Azure.WaitUntil.Completed,
                    sender,
                    recipient,
                    subject,
                    base64Content);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
                //SvrErrorMsg = $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}";
                // Log the exception or take appropriate action
            }
        }
```

Below is the unit test I have written so far but I am getting a compile error stating :
***'ISetup<EmailClient, Task>' does not contain a definition for 'ReturnsAsync' and the best extension method overload 'SequenceExtensions.ReturnsAsync(ISetupSequentialResult<Task>, EmailSendOperation)' requires a receiver of type 'Moq.Language.ISetupSequentialResult<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<NUnit_TestProject.EmailSendOperation>>'***

this is on the following lines:

```
EmailClientClientMock.Setup(x => x.SendAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), null, CancellationToken.None))
                    .ReturnsAsync(emailSendOperationMock.Object);
```

Below is the test I have written so far:

```
        [Test]
        public async Task Email_SendEmailSuccessfully()
        {
            // Arrange
            var configurationMock = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
            configurationMock.Setup(x => x["CommunicationServiceConnectionString"]).Returns("YourConnectionString");
            configurationMock.Setup(x => x["EmailSettings:Subject"]).Returns("YourSubject");
            configurationMock.Setup(x => x["EmailSettings:Sender"]).Returns("YourSender");
            configurationMock.Setup(x => x["EmailSettings:Recipient"]).Returns("YourRecipient");

            var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger>();

            // Mocking the SecretClient for testing purposes
            var EmailClientClientMock = new Mock<EmailClient>();
            var emailSendOperationMock = new Mock<EmailSendOperation>();

            var _EmailSendOperation = new EmailSendOperation();

            //ERROR:
            //error CS1929: 'ISetup<EmailClient, Task<EmailSendOperation>>' does not contain a definition for 'ReturnsAsync' and the best extension method overload 'SequenceExtensions.ReturnsAsync<EmailSendOperation>(ISetupSequentialResult<Task<EmailSendOperation>>, EmailSendOperation)'
            //requires a receiver of type 'Moq.Language.ISetupSequentialResult<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<NUnit_TestProject.EmailSendOperation>>'
            EmailClientClientMock.Setup(x => x.SendAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), null, CancellationToken.None))
                .ReturnsAsync(emailSendOperationMock.Object);
            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

            var myHelper = new Helper();

            await myHelper.SendEmail(configurationMock.Object, "YourHtmlContent", "YourKeyVaultUrl", loggerMock.Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

SendAsync method in your EmailClient class returns a Task. But, in your test setup, you're trying to return a Mock. below changes should fix this.

```cs
EmailSendOperation emailSendOperation = new EmailSendOperation(); // Or however you instantiate this

// If you need to mock EmailSendOperation
// var emailSendOperationMock = new Mock<EmailSendOperation>();
// Use emailSendOperationMock.Object in the Task.FromResult

EmailClientClientMock.Setup(x => x.SendAsync(
    WaitUntil.Completed, 
    It.IsAny<string>(), 
    It.IsAny<string>(), 
    It.IsAny<string>(), 
    It.IsAny<string>())
).ReturnsAsync(Task.FromResult(emailSendOperation)); // or emailSendOperationMock.Object if you're mocking
```